# Read BigGeoTIFF multiband GDAL using Python

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, multi-band

I'm trying to read\load BigGeoTIFF multi-band raster (>4GB), using GDAL module in python but I can't seem to make it. At first the error was that BigGeoTIFF format is not supported by GDAL and libtiff versions, but according to this [document](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) I have the required versions. I also saw somewhere (can't find it now for some reason) that you need to specifically enable the BigGeoTIFF format in GDAL but I don't know how to do so. Anyways, now when I try to read the raster with:

```
source = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\california_merge.tif"
dataset = gdal.Open(source)
print type(dataset)
>>>NoneType
```

When I use this code on <4GB multi-band raster I get the desired result

```
source = r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\california_merge_clip.tif"
dataset = gdal.Open(source)
print type(dataset)
>>>osgeo.gdal.Dataset
```

What can I do to be able to read (and later process) BigGeoTIFF file in Python (version 2.7 on win 10)

Comment: How much memory does your pc have?

Comment: How many bands does BigGeotiff raster have? In this case, for reducing size, you can use **gdal_translate** command (by using -b parameter) to extract each individual band previously and try it out.

Comment: 8GB, 4-band raster

Comment: Please edit your question and specify what version of GDAL and where you installed it from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install a version of GDAL via Anaconda that permits reading BigTIFFs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291921/cannot-install-a-version-of-gdal-via-anaconda-that-permits-reading-bigtiffs)

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you can check if BigTIFF is supported [like this](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/be84f529864b27e8bcd8f0cef25efabebb73cc0b/autotest/gcore/tiff_ovr.py#L764):

```
md = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').GetMetadata()
if md['DMD_CREATIONOPTIONLIST'].find('BigTIFF') == -1:
    return 'BigTIFF is not supported'
```

You can also enable exceptions to see the reason why the image can't be read (gdal.Open() will raise an exception):

```
gdal.UseExceptions()
```

Comment: I ran this code and I got 'BigTIFF is not supported', I don't now how to enable it since I have the required version of 'gdal' and 'libtiff'. Is there any other module that supports BigGeoTiff?