# Cannot install a version of GDAL via Anaconda that permits reading BigTIFFs

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, anaconda, bigtiff

I have some BigTiff files that I need to read into Python using gdal to do some analyses. According to GDAL's documentation:

> When built with internal libtiff or with libtiff >= 4.0, GDAL also supports reading and writing BigTIFF files (evolution of the TIFF format to support files larger than 4 GB).

My version of libtiff is 4.0.9, so there should be no problem. However, if I try

```
bt = gdal.Open('path_to_bigtiff.tif'),
```

`bt` is a NoneType. I tested to ensure that non-BigTIFF files are readable with gdal.Open(), which they are.

Furthermore, if I check the list of gdal's supported drivers' metadata like this:

```
md = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').GetMetadata()
if md['DMD_CREATIONOPTIONLIST'].find('BigTIFF') == -1:
    return 'BigTIFF is not supported'
```

BigTIFFs are not supported. My version of gdal is 2.2.2.

Using Anaconda, I created a new environment with

```
conda create --name test1 gdal
```

but I get the same result--gdal 2.2.2 is installed along with libtiff 4.0.9 and BigTiff files still cannot be read.

Using Anaconda again, I created a new environment with

```
conda create --name test2 gdal=2.3.1 -c conda-forge
```

but when I run `import gdal` in the test2 environment, I get the error message

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

**How can I install a version of gdal that will permit me to load BigTiffs**? I would also like it to be compatible with rasterio and fiona if possible.

Here is the output from `conda info` for the environment containing 2.2.2:
(geoenv) C:\Users\Jon>conda info

```
     active environment : geoenv
    active env location : C:\Users\Jon\Anaconda3\envs\geoenv
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\Jon\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Jon\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.9
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\Jon\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\Jon\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Jon\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Jon\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.9 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.15063
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: @Luke I added the output of conda info. I have tried every possible install combo I could think of--when I install from conda-forge, I always get the ImportError, and when I install from conda, I can't read BigTiffs.

Comment: @Luke I also just tried installing gdal 2.2.4 from conda-forge--same result. Cannot import.

Comment: I having this problem even after the conda create -n testgdal -c conda-forge gdal vs2015_runtime=14 procedure. It appears a problem related to DLL. And when I don't install this gdal version the problem is that the spyder can't read BigTIFF files. I don't know what to do anymore :(

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151288)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issues:

1. The Anaconda default gdal may be built [without BigTIFF support](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9887).  If I create a non conda-forge env, i.e  `conda create -n testgdal gdal` I can reproduce the `md['DMD_CREATIONOPTIONLIST'].find('BigTIFF') == -1` no BigTIFF issue.
2. There seems to be an incompatibility between the latest version of conda and vs2015_runtime and conda-forge. I updated my conda to 4.5.9 to match yours and vs2015_runtime (the Visual C++ runtime for applications compiled with MS Visual Studio) was upgraded from 14 to 15.  If I then create a conda env with gdal from the conda-forge channel, I get the same `ImportError: DLL load failed`.

Fix:

If I create a conda-forge env and specify vs2015_runtime=14, everything works:

```
conda create -n testgdal -c conda-forge gdal vs2015_runtime=14
activate testgdal 

(testgdal)  python
Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2018, 11:48:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>> md = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').GetMetadata()
>>> md['DMD_CREATIONOPTIONLIST'].find('BigTIFF')
2953
```

Comment: I did leave out an important step--the issues started after I updated conda. I thought that previously I could read BigTiffs but I wasn't sure, and I had forgotten until I read your answer that I had updated conda this morning. I'll check tomorrow if specifying the v14 runtime fixes things.

Comment: It worked--could you add a little about what the runtime variable does? Now off to make it play nice with rasterio...

Comment: @Jon edited. It's not a variable, it's a package

Comment: Can you use jupyter with testgdal kernel?

Comment: It raises a lot of conflicts actually. Let me look into that

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422817/jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-8-notimplementederror

Comment: Then create a new env, with python 3.7, gdal and jupyter. `conda create -n my env -v conda-forge gdal jupyter python=3.7`

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/219) the discussion on the conda-forge lists with the background on the DLL load error. I encountered the same issue where it stopped working after doing a `conda update gdal`, and pinning vs2015_runtime to 14 works as noted.

Comment: hey can you share more insights? I have the same error when opening a BigTiff "ERROR 4: This is a BigTIFF file. BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff." 
with GDAL 2.3.2, vs2015_runtime and libtiff 4.0.10