# Installing GDAL with Anaconda

Tags: python, gdal, anaconda

I just did a fresh install of Anaconda3 and am trying to add GDAL/OGR. I've tried installing with both `conda install gdal` and `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`.  In both cases, the install completes successfully, but when I `import gdal`, it raises the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jhook\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
  File "C:\Users\Jhook\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jhook\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jhook\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jhook\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've found several workarounds out there, but most date back a few years and don't reflect more recent updates or changes.  Is there a fix for this problem that works in 2018?

Comment: What OS are you running this on? How did you call `import gdal`, via a terminal or an IDE?

Comment: Running on Windows 10.  Result is the same for `import gdal` from a terminal and from PyCharm.

Comment: Try ‘from osgeo import gdal’

Comment: `from osgeo import gdal` results in the same message

Comment: Can you please confirm you are running Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.6.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be an incompatibility between the latest version of conda and vs2015_runtime and conda-forge gdal.

If I create a conda-forge env and specify vs2015_runtime=14, everything works:

```
conda create -n testgdal -c conda-forge gdal vs2015_runtime=14 

activate testgdal 

(testgdal) python 

Python 3.6.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 26 2018, 11:48:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  

>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>>
```

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/291932

Comment: Thanks for this. Was going crazy for a while. Shouldn't this get done automatically by anaconda?

Comment: It should, but conda-forge is not Anaconda. It's a separate community led channel and occasionally things get out of sync

Answer (score 1):

I've spent the day with that issue, and for me what worked was to install from wheels, as detailed on that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ybddFC80fU

It is pretty simple. The only thing I had to change was to also install Fiona from wheel first, otherwise I had an error saying "a GDAL API version must be specified...[]"

Comment: Could you write what the steps are from that video? I think it would make your answer more helpful and more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

The following works reliably for me Ubuntu 20.04:

```
conda update conda    
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev gdal-bin

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

# check gdal version with 
gdal-config --version

echo '
name: raster-pipeline
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.7.*
- cython
- numpy
- ipython
- libspatialindex
- libgdal=USE_GDAL_VERSION
- gdal=USE_GDAL_VERSION
- pip
- pip:
  - numpy>=1.18.5
  - GDAL==USE_GDAL_VERSION
  - pyproj>=2.6.1.post1
  - rasterio>=1.1.5
' > raster_pipeline.yml
  
conda env create -f raster_pipeline.yml -v 
 
conda activate raster_pipeline 
python -c "from osgeo import gdal"
conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said there seems to be an incompatibility issue. Creating a new environment solved the problem. This worked for me

Go to anaconda navigator --> environments --> Create --> GDAL
Go to anaconda prompt --> activate GDAL --> conda install gdal

Hope this will do. But you have to install other libraries again in this new environment.