# "RasterioIOError: This is a BigTIFF file. BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff" error message

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, bigtiff

I am trying to read a raster ".tif" file with rasterio:

```
import rasterio
raster_path = r'.........\file.tif'
raster = rasterio.open(raster_path)
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
"RasterioIOError: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff"
```

Apparently, the raster file I am trying to open with rasterio is a BIGTIFF (which I  had no idea about since I cannot see anything in the properties of the file when being opened with ArcMap that suggests such a thing, plus it's not a particularly big file -less than 1GB-).

I have seen similar questions posted here more than a year ago, but they don't really offer any solution.

I have:

```
GDAL     =>  2.4.1
libtiff  =>  4.0.10
rasterio =>  1.0.21
```

Comment: I've encountered this before when installing in windows with anaconda and the `conda-forge` feedstock. I've found `gdal==2.3.3` and `libtiff==4.0.10` works (with a variety of `rasterio` versions).

Comment: If it works with GDAL 2.3.3, shouldn't it also work with GDAL 2.4.1? Anyway, I've installed GDAL 2.3.3, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install a version of GDAL via Anaconda that permits reading BigTIFFs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291921/cannot-install-a-version-of-gdal-via-anaconda-that-permits-reading-bigtiffs). See point 1 of the accepted answer and use `-c conda-forge` when you install.

Comment: From that link I've used the following commands  =>  
"conda create -n testgdal -c conda-forge gdal vs2015_runtime=14" and "activate testgdal"..........error still present

Comment: I'm still stuck with this issue. Any help much appreciated. From the possible duplicate I understand that "conda create -n testgdal -c conda-forge gdal vs2015_runtime=14" and "activate testgdal" solves the problem. I don't know what a 'conda-forge env' is, but if I use those two commands I can see that md['DMD_CREATIONOPTIONLIST'].find('BigTIFF') throws a number different to -1. However, when I run my script, none of the packages I have installed can be imported. They have disappeared. Does it mean I have to install them again?

Comment: Could anyone help on this? I still haven't managed to read BigTIFF files with rasterio/gdal

Comment: What were the similar questions that you reviewed and tried?

Comment: Got help needed on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336468/how-should-i-use-a-conda-forge-environment?noredirect=1#comment548995_336468

Comment: Apparently one of the arguments that need to be included in the `rasterio.open` method is `bigtiff=YES`. However for me this still didn't solve the problem. Please see https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1796

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work on Windows with Anaconda following these steps:

I first downloaded whl files for Gdal and Rasterio as suggested on the [rasterio
page](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) (e.g. from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio) for rasterio). I chose files for python 3.7 as I already had this combination working for big tiffs on a Linux platform.

Then in Anaconda:

```
conda create -n w1 python=3.7
conda activate w1
pip install GDAL-3.2.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
pip install rasterio-1.2.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```